# How to access value outside of foreach on Android Studio, Kotlin, Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am writing a code for the access room database. I want to use some values outside of foEeach. for example:
my DAO query is:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE id = :id ")
fun getSingleUserDetails(id: Int): List<UsersEntity>
```

and accessing on MainActivity:

```
val db = AppDB.getApplicationDatabase(this)
    db.boxLocationsDao().getSingleUserDetails(rowId).forEach {
        val rowId = it.id
        val userName = it.name }
```

In this case I can use all values within the forEach {}, but now I want to use the "userName" (or any other values) outside of forEach's "{}". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple you can create a variable `rowId` and `userName` before `forEach{}` and store value inside `forEach{}` so you can use stored value outside forEach.

I have attached the code below.

```
var rowId:Int = 0
var userName:String = ""

val db = AppDB.getApplicationDatabase(this)
        db.boxLocationsDao().getSingleUserDetails(rowId).forEach {
            rowId = it.id
            userName = it.name 
}

//use **rowId** and **userName** variables here(outside foreEach{})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this answer does not help me. the userName variable value is still blank outside of foreach {},

Comment: Given answer is 100% correct. If you are getting username blank then db.boxLocationsDao().getSingleUserDetails(rowId) is returning empty so please check that answer is correct but maybe this function (getSingleUserDetails) returns empty data or data